# error in saving image in server

Tags: php, image, server, base64

my php script looks like this:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect('mysql.hostinger.in','username','password','databasename');

$data = $_POST['img'];
$name=$_POST['name'];

$data = base64_decode($data);
$file = 'images/'. md5($name) . '.png';
if (file_exists($file)) {
            unlink($file);

         } 
$success = file_put_contents($file,$data);
echo "success";


?>
```

There are 2 problems:

1. the images are saved in server but have size is zero?
2. when i am putting large Image string as parameter the error shows up "`Size of a request header field exceeds server limit`."

please help me out what should i do? and for testing purpose i have converted Image to `base64` string via online site.

Comment: `$_POST['img']` does not contain the image. `$_FILES['img']` might, though.

Comment: yes..but it's not direct image...it's image in string form..?? :)